# Does the vimeo nodejs API support uploading using the 'pull' approach

Tags: node.js, vimeo

I'm trying to use the pull approach for vimeo api uploading, but the vimeo UI shows the films 'uploading' forever, and none of the metadata I've included in the post request makes it to vimeo either.

My request looke like this (i've redacted some of it). The signedURL works and has an expiry of 1 day.

```
{
  path: '/users/xxxxx/videos',
  query: {
    upload: {
      approach: 'pull',
      size: 27759876,
      link: 'https://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxx/xxxxxxx%2F0079e513eb90623236b9fce0ebdc5a29%2Ffilm%2F0079e513eb90623236b9fce0ebdc5a29.m4v?GoogleAccessId=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&Expires=1599054191&Signature=jLEDJ8iNaRC4eDn37DHoCilhKMmDk04h17Vu%2FbDUJbNFxdbjR9CowMQWdn95MdrX....etc'
    },
    name: 'xxxx',
    description: 'xxxxxxx',
    privacy: {
      download: true,
      embed: 'private',
      comments: 'nobody',
      view: 'anybody'
    }
  },
  method: 'post'
}
```

and the response back from vimeo appears valid - with lots of vimeo metadata and a vimeo id for the uploaded film.

Looking at the nodejs api on github I only see tus upload approach examples - so now I'm wondering if the client actually supports the pull approach. Has anyone been able to get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `params` property instead of `query`; using `params` will put your metadata into the request body instead of providing it as a query parameter.

`params` is mentioned in the docs as part of the `upload` method, but it should be used with the `request` method when making a POST or PATCH.

I think your example request is fine, just swap `params` for `query`

https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js#uploading-videos
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.js/blob/c7a1a16c1805539a00bc37d661b81c10e2108a75/example/upload.js#L63

Comment: Yes, I had already tried using params rather than query, but the result is exactly the same. I saw that query was being used in the tests on github so tried that.  I wondered if i should be using client.upload, but the 1st arg to that is a local path, so is not relevant for the pull approach. It's as if the payload (whether params or query) is being completely ignored.

Comment: Hmm, might need to reach out to Vimeo Support then (https://vimeo.com/help/contact).